# analog to glib's object model?

Tags: c++, c

Please tell me about C/C++ libraries you know of which provide a framework of objects resembling the one of glib library. The main function the framework must have is the option to set different properties/attributes to objects and subscribe users to attribute change notification events.

And it would be great if it had a licence weaker than GPL (e.g BSD or MIT or LGPL) because I'm going to use it in a proprietary product. Commercial ones will also suffice.

E.g. I know about libsigc++ library but it provides only a notification chain framework but not a whole object model with properties and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The one I picked is [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) and is LGPL licensed. It has a class hierarchy based on [QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html). It supports properties as well as a signal/slot mechanism, which allows you to get notified about changes by connecting an object's signal to either a pre-existing slot, or a slot you wrote.

The signals/slots mechanism is described here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/signalsandslots.html